# Why is sometimes more difficult to lift a baby?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, gravity, weight

I have a small cousin and she enjoys when I pick her up, which I can do pretty easily.

Sometimes though she decides she wants to make my life difficult, and when she decides so, she tells me she is "being heavy" and I can actually feel a substantial difference when I lift her, until her feet are not in contact with the ground anymore.

Now, assuming that this is not just an impression, what could be the cause of this? I assume that it is about how the force exerted by my hands is transmitted to her body.. or maybe usually she "helps" with her hands when I take her (even though I don't think so) and when she is being heavy she is just laying down..

What do you guys think?

Comment: Is she less heavy when you pick her up in close to your own body, than when you pick her up from an arms length away? If so, then it's a lever effect, I think, and she may make herself effectively heavier, to you, by moving away from you.

Comment: @AcidJazz Hi! I don't think that's the reason, there is no difference in distance when this happens :)

Comment: If she just lets her body go completely slack, you will find it much harder to pick her up than when she participates. For example, if you grab her in the armpits, it's much harder to lift her if she does not help by keeping her arms down. The same goes for other body parts too.

Comment: I guess it could also have to do with expectations: when she tells you "I'm heavy" you tense your muscles more in advance, since you expect her to resist the lift in some way. Your muscles then need to expend the gravitational energy and the additional "I'm more tense because my cousin doesn't want to be picked up"-energy, so to you it feels more difficult.

Comment: I would agree with the previous comment, if the child does not move around her arms and legs  in any significant or obvious way, then as NoEigenValue says above, imo it can only be your perception of how much effort you need, and your bodies response to that. Have you tried sweets, kids can almost fly up to those:)

Comment: @hdhondt That is probably the cause. But can you elaborate on how that translates on a higher required force? :)

Comment: @AcidJazz I don't want to rule out that, but I think it doesn't just come down to perception.. Will try with the sweets though :P

Comment: @Ant. Take the simple case I used before: you pick her up under the arms. If she holds her arms down, you just have to lift. If she doesn't you also have to squeeze (but not too hard...), to make sure your hands don't slip. Similarly, if you grab her by the middle, if she stays stiff, it's only a lifting exercise. If she flops, you have to spend extra effort holding her.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you "can actually feel a substantial difference when I lift her, until her feet are not in contact with the ground anymore". That makes perfect sense i.e. she is also participating in the lifting process by pushing off the ground except when she's being difficult.

Once she's off the ground, as long as you're holding her in the same way and she isn't making any other squirmy motion that makes it harder for you to maintain your grip, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

From [Making yourself heavier](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111009081657AAIAwPQ)

> Yes, it is possible to make yourself harder to lift. By shifting your center of gravity , which is usually referred to as your hips, down you can make it much harder to be lifted. It depends on which kind of lift, but this usually does the trick. Shifting your center of gravity does not make you heavier. It shifts the point where your body is balanced. 
>   If someone tries to lift you up, try bending your knees. That shifts your center of balance so that you are harder to pick up.

If this idea is true, it is impressive how much intuitive physical knowledge we have at an early age.